# Sharing iCloud storage between family members

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

Is there a way to share iCloud storage between family members?

I included my wife's iPhone into Family sharing, but I would like to have one storage bucket (20G) that would allow us both Apple ID accounts to backup more then default 5G per device. Is it possible?

Comment: Basically this is asking if account A needs 5.5 GB and account B needs 10.5 GB, can they avoid paying for 40 GB (20 x 2) and still have backup fit in one 20 GB payment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is coming in iOS 11 (see [iMore](https://www.imore.com/icloud-ios-11)). From that page:

> .. yes, now you can share that data with your family, with up to six
>   people using one storage plan for backups, files, and photos.
>   Presumably, each family member's files are only available to that
>   person, unlike, say, Family Sharing of iTunes, iBooks, and App Store
>   content.

Comment: Yes, now in Settings on your iPhone in iOS 11 tap your Apple ID Account at the top, then `iCloud`, then `Manage Storage` and above `Change Storage Plan` you should see a `Share With Family` button. It's probably only available if you already have the 200GB or 2TB plans.

Comment: "Presumably, each family member's files are only available to that person" I wish Apple would make this explicitly clear.  I don't see it answered anywhere explicitly on the Family Sharing pages for iCloud Storage.

Comment: In 2022, this requires "iCloud+", which starts at $0.99 to share the 50GB with family members (and has some other benefits, such as custom email domains, anonymized email addresses, etc).

Answer (score 11):

Update 2017/2018: It appears Apple finally allows sharing iCloud storage between family members (see the newly accepted answer). Glad to hear it!

## Original:

The correct answer is No, there is not.  Apple does not let you share iCloud Storage with family members, unfortunately.

Here's a forum link where this has been discussed:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6543858

You can share your account and password, but then the storage is yours and not really sharing with a sub-account. Each individual Apple ID gets their own paid/gifted/free storage quota and any one account can bump up their storage only and it doesn't affect any other AppleID storage capacity - family membership regardless.

Comment: Note that as of iOS 11 this is no longer the case and Family Sharing for iCloud Storage now exists.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208147